# Transition current density to generate electromagnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, second-quantization

The second quantization quantize the electromagnetic field $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\Phi$ (vector and scalar potential): they became operators. The vector potential in case of an external current source $\boldsymbol{J}$ is given by Maxwell equations:

$$ \Box \boldsymbol{A} = \mu_0 \boldsymbol{J} $$

Some physicists, like Julian Schwinger were [against the operator formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_field) of ($\boldsymbol{A}$,$\Phi$). From quantum mechanics we know also the [probability density current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current). By using this formalism, considering an electronic transition between state $n$ to lower state $k$ ($E_n > E_k$), why could we not express the electromagnetic field $\boldsymbol{A_{n,k}}$ generated (the single photon in fact) by Maxwell equations:

$$ \Box \boldsymbol{A_{n,k}} = \mu_0 \boldsymbol{J_{n,k}} $$

with this kind of current source distribution (for single electron atom only):

$$ \boldsymbol{J_{n,k}} \simeq \frac{e \hbar}{2 m_e} \left[ \boldsymbol{\Psi_n} . \left( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \boldsymbol{\Psi_k}^* \right) - \boldsymbol{\Psi_k^*} . \left( \boldsymbol{\nabla} \Psi_n \right) \right] $$

which is a 3 spatial vectors (scalar product between spinors), with $\boldsymbol{\Psi_n}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Psi_k}$ the bounded electronic $2 \times 1$ Dirac Spinor of states $n$ and $k$, and $*$ stands for complex conjugate. That looks like probability current density but this time for a transition. We have $ \boldsymbol{J_{n,k}} \propto e^{i \omega_{n,k} t}$ with $\omega_{n,k} = (E_n - E_k)/\hbar$. Did you see an expression like this in old textbooks ? It is really simple and intuitive (probably wrong, I don't know) but I cannot find it, or a similar formula. The states should depends on $\theta$ and $\phi$ (Dirac Hydrogen states) otherwise for radial Hydrogen states the vector potential is $A(r) \boldsymbol{e_r}$ then the magnetic field is zero ($\boldsymbol{\nabla} \wedge \boldsymbol{A} = 0$) and there is no electromagnetic radiation.

I find this topic very interesting, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I found the answer in the [work of Roger Boudet](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-85550-7). Every transitions are explained by means of transition current, this a concurrent theory of QED (without divergence... that helps). It is a complicated textbook but spontaneous emission, photo-electric effect are explained, an enormous work that should be seen.

**EDIT**

An attempt of explanation for the Lamb shift is provided but it is not explained inside the book.